# Adding simple upload adapter to ckeditor in Angular

Tags: angular, file-upload, ckeditor

I did started classic ckeditor in my angular project by installing...

```
npm install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular
npm install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic
```

In my component I've imported it...

```
import * as ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
```

initiated object...

```
  public Editor = ClassicEditor;
```

and in template started like this

```
        <ckeditor [config]="{ toolbar: [ 'heading', '|', 'bold', 'italic' ] }" name="Blog" placeholder="About your ride" [(ngModel)]="formModel.Blog" required [editor]="Editor" data="<p>Blog!</p>"></ckeditor>
```

Now I want to add Simple upload adapter to this editor.

I did install

```
npm install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-upload
```

Then there is written

- Add the SimpleUploadAdapter to my plugin list
  https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/image-upload/simple-upload-adapter.html

And I'm stuck here. I don't know what's and where is that plugin list.

Any ideas how to add image upload to my ckeditor ?

**Update**
In my component did this:

```
  public Editor = ClassicEditor;
  public config = { plugins: [SimpleUploadAdapter]};
```

In my HTML calling the same

```
<ckeditor [config]="{ toolbar: [ 'heading', '|', 'bold', 'italic' ] }" name="Blog" placeholder="About your ride" [(ngModel)]="formModel.Blog" required [editor]="Editor" data="<p>Blog!</p>"></ckeditor>
```

getting error

> Uncaught CKEditorError: ckeditor-duplicated-modules: Some CKEditor 5
> modules are duplicated

Comment: ClassicEditor
    .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ), {
        plugins: [ SimpleUploadAdapter, ... ],
        toolbar: [ ... ],
        simpleUpload: {
            // Feature configuration.
        }
    } )
    .then( ... )
    .catch( ... );

Comment: shall I put it in ngOnInit() { of my component ?  what about SimpleUploadAdapter, ... and  toolbar: [ ... ],   ???

Comment: Right.. I agree the docs are a bit vague on this. It seems ‘plugins’ is just a config item so you can do something like (in your component, just below public Editor): public config = { plugins: [SimpleUploadAdapter]} and in your html use <ckeditor [config]="config” .....>. You can add the other items in that config object as well (toolbar etc)

Comment: i think I'm doing something wrong, updated m question please have a look

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I got this working by using a custom upload adapter instead of *SimpleUploadAdapter* - i.e.

1. Copy the **class only** from here: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/deep-dive/upload-adapter.html#the-complete-implementation
   (I adapted it slightly to avoid TypeScript errors, and changed the URL)
2. Import the class into your Angular component
3. Add a `ready` handler that provides an implementation for `createUploadAdapter`

So my code is:

**my-upload-adapter.ts:**

```js
export class MyUploadAdapter {
    loader: any;
    xhr: any;
    constructor( loader ) {
        this.loader = loader;
    }
    upload() {
        return this.loader.file
            .then( file => new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
                this._initRequest();
                this._initListeners( resolve, reject, file );
                this._sendRequest( file );
            } ) );
    }
    abort() {
        if ( this.xhr ) {
            this.xhr.abort();
        }
    }
    _initRequest() {
        const xhr = this.xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open( 'POST', 'http://yourserver/upload', true ); // TODO change the URL
        xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    }
    _initListeners( resolve, reject, file ) {
        const xhr = this.xhr;
        const loader = this.loader;
        const genericErrorText = `Couldn't upload file: ${ file.name }.`;
        xhr.addEventListener( 'error', () => reject( genericErrorText ) );
        xhr.addEventListener( 'abort', () => reject() );
        xhr.addEventListener( 'load', () => {
            const response = xhr.response;
            if ( !response || response.error ) {
                return reject( response && response.error ? response.error.message : genericErrorText );
            }
            resolve( {
                default: response.url
            } );
        } );
        if ( xhr.upload ) {
            xhr.upload.addEventListener( 'progress', evt => {
                if ( evt.lengthComputable ) {
                    loader.uploadTotal = evt.total;
                    loader.uploaded = evt.loaded;
                }
            } );
        }
    }
    _sendRequest( file ) {
        const data = new FormData();
        data.append( 'upload', file );
        this.xhr.send( data );
    }
}
```

**my.component.html:**

```html
<ckeditor ... (ready)="onReady($event)"></ckeditor>
```

**my.component.ts:**

```js
import * as ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
import { MyUploadAdapter } from '../my-upload-adapter';

//...

export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    Editor = ClassicEditor;

//...

    onReady(editor: ClassicEditor): void {
        editor.plugins.get( 'FileRepository' ).createUploadAdapter = ( loader ) => {
            return new MyUploadAdapter( loader );
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: everything looks good, except authorization process. error says unauthorized while trying to upload image

Comment: Yes, you would have to add whatever authorization your server requires to the request, after `xhr.open` - e.g. if the server uses 'basic' autorization, you'd add something like:
`xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password));`

(Although a XMLHttpRequest opened by a browser should already have the authorization it needs)

Comment: @RobertFromont When the image is uploaded correctly, the browser deletes the image and shows an alert with the error. Why?

Comment: @HessianMad I'm not seeing this, but it's possible that the response to the upload request isn't correct or isn't being interpreted correctly. `MyUploadAdapter` expects the response to be a JSON object that specifies the `url` of the image, something like: 
`{ "url" : "http://hostname/path/to/image.png" }` - if the response has a different structure, or the URL is wrong, then I guess you'd see an error. Hopefully the error message itself has a clue about what's going wrong?

Comment: Hi, thanks for sharing the code. I am facing an issue with saving images to editor data. here is the editor data "<figure class=\"image\"><img></figure><p>some image</p><p>ss</p><p>some hellow</p>" @RobertFromont

Answer (score 1):

Roberts answer is OK, but his code is very long and complex for nothing.
Here is a more effective MyUploadAdapter class.

```
class MyUploadAdapter {
  constructor(private loader: any, private http: HttpClient) {}
  upload() {
    return this.loader.file.then((file) => {
      return this.http
        .post(
          'https://your.url',
          new FormData().append('upload', file)
        )
        .subscribe();
    });
  }
  abort() {
    console.error('aborted');
  }
}
```

You only need to send the http when calling the class.